# Create column based on unique values

Tags: r, dataframe

I'd like to create columns in a data frame based on the unique values from a single column.

E.g.

```
Column1
A
B
C
```

Into

```
A     B      C
True  False  False
False True   False
False False  True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `table`

```
!!table(1:nrow(df1), df1$Column1)
#       A     B     C
#  1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#  2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#  3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

Or using `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(df1$Column1)!=0
#         A     B     C
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

Or using `model.matrix`

```
 model.matrix(~Column1-1, df1)!=0
 #  Column1A Column1B Column1C
 #1     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
 #2    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE
 #3    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also use a loop,

```
sapply(df$Column1, function(i) grepl(i, df$Column1))
#         A     B     C
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `dcast` from `reshape2` package

```
library(reshape2)
!is.na(dcast(df, Column1 ~ Column1))[, -1]

#       A     B     C
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```